# How to dispense child element from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me with this. There is HTML code:

```
<h3>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="country" value="us" /> United States
    </label>
</h3>
<p>Some content goes here</p>
```

I want to toggle **p** element by clicking on the **h3** tag, but I don't wan't to toggle if I clicked on the **label**

```
$('h3').click(function() {
   // Does something goes here?
   $(this).next('p').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Why not? Isn't the idea that content in p is connected to the checkbox that you are toggling?

Comment: I'm assuming that label means the actual text, not the HTML element.

Comment: (the checkbox is toggled by the label)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to check the target of the action

```
$('h3').click(function(e) {
   // if they clicked the h3 only
   if (this == e.target) {
     $(this).next('p').toggle();
   }
}
```

altCognito's suggestion would work also but it is more code.

Answer (score 2):

You want to stopPropagation()

```
$('h3').click(function() {
   // Does something goes here?
   $(this).next('p').toggle();
}
$('label').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```